# iOS:Draw Multiple Lines Using CGContextAddLineToPoint

Tags: ios, xcode, cgcontext

I am writing this code in drawrect

```
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 10);
CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor yellowColor].CGColor);


CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 502,530);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, x2, y2);


CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 502, 530);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, x3, y3);

CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 502, 530);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, x4, y4);

NSLog(@"%d,%d--%d,%d--%d,%d",x2,y2,x3,y3,x4,y4);



CGContextStrokePath(context);
```

But this code always draw only two lines which are incorrect
It never draws the third line
When i give static values instead of x and y  code works fine with three lines
When I NSLOG x and y I get proper desired values
but lines are not drawn according to that
I want to draw 4-5 lines with continuesly changing coordinates

Please tell me where I am going wrong 
Or any other alternative to solve this problem

Comment: Are x2, y2, etc CGFloat values?

Comment: they are int values Int will work or not

Comment: But making them CGfloat is also not working out

Comment: If you are drawing closer then decrease the line width and check

Answer (score 2):

[image]

The above code is working fine, they are making three individual lines (the starting point is same for all(502, 530)). I think you are giving ending position for two points (like x3,y3 or x4,y4) are same directions, that is why you are getting two lines only, if you want to differentiate those lines you can make the lines in different color like...

```
int x2, y2, x3, y3,x4, y4;
x2 = 100;
y2 = 100;
x3 = 200;
y3 = 200;
x4 = 200;
y4 = 50;

CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 10);

// line 1
CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor yellowColor].CGColor);    
CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 502,530);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, x2, y2);
CGContextStrokePath(context);

// line 2
CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor blueColor].CGColor);    
CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 502, 530);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, x3, y3);
CGContextStrokePath(context);

// line 3
CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor redColor].CGColor);    
CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 502, 530);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, x4, y4);
CGContextStrokePath(context);

NSLog(@"%d,%d--%d,%d--%d,%d",x2,y2,x3,y3,x4,y4);
```

Comment: This is the case with me also
when i am giving hardcoded static coordinates i am getting three lines drawn
But when I want line to be changed continuesly and value of x and y change continuesly I do not get desired result
I only get two lines drawn I have checked value of x and y are proper and not overlapping
Is there any other way to draw 3-4 lines